# Error from collections module in Python

Tags: python

I am getting the following errror when a python program is run

> File
>   "/home/user/Desktop/important/paper/ordereddict.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from collections import MutableMapping ImportError: cannot
>   import name MutableMapping

When I tried import collections it works fine. Please help.

I am using version Python 2.5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`collections.MutableMapping`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.MutableMapping) was introduced only in Python 2.6, so you need at least that version of Python to use your `ordereddict` module.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Python 2.6 to use MutableMapping